# Select last rows from same name

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to list fruit names from my table but I don't want to list more than one fruit name from the same user

my table looks like this

```
id     |    username         |  fruits
------------------------------------------
1      |    John             |  strawberry
2      |    Nick             |  banana
3      |    Ben              |  apple
4      |    Nick             |  pear
5      |    John             |  cherry
```

output should be like this;

```
5  |  John     |    cherry
4  |  Nick     |    pear
3  |  Ben      |    apple
```

I tried this code but it list first fruits

```
"SELECT * FROM mytable GROUP BY username DESC"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the "nice" way to do this with `ROW_NUMBER`, assuming you are using MySQL 8+:

```
SELECT username, fruits
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY username ORDER BY id DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

On earlier versions of MySQL, we can join to a subquery which finds the most recent record for each `username`:

```
SELECT t1.username, t1.fruits
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT username, MAX(id) AS max_id
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY username
) t2
    ON t1.username = t2.username AND
       t1.id = t2.max_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use `in`

```
SELECT a.username, a.fruits
FROM table_name a
where (a.username,a.id) in
(
    SELECT username, MAX(id) as mid 
    FROM table_name
    GROUP BY username
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use correlated subquery

```
select id,username, fruits
from tablename a
where id in (select max(id) from tablename b where a.username=b.username)
```

Answer (score 0):

this will also work apart from other answers:

```
select `username`,`fruits` from (select `id12`,`username`,`fruits`,RANK() over 
(PARTITION  by `username`
order by `id12` desc )as rn   from Table1)m where rn=1;
```

check:https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vmWYczLQLanhvcqChuRL4b/0

Answer (score 0):

You can use correlated subquery :

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.id = (select max(t1.id) from table t1 where t1.username = t.username);
```